# Find prime factors and reverse strings

Tags: beginner, primes, bash, linux

I'm currently taking an introductory course to Bash at my university, and was hoping to get some peer-review from whoever might have some time.

**Full disclosure**: the quality of the code isn't considered when the professor gives a grade as assignments only yield a ***PASS!***

I've had very limited exposure to bash before taking this course, so I'm hoping You might have some understanding for any lackluster scripting.

Our current module covers functions, case-switches, loops and parameters (options, commands, arguments).

I just finished the last assignment and was hoping You could have a quick overview of it and see if I'm making any common mistakes and tell me how to correct them.

The same code may be easier to read on **[GitHub](https://github.com/Todai88/bth_linux/blob/master/kmom03/commands/commands.bash)**.

```
#!/bin/bash


# Script name
SCRIPT=$( basename "$0" )

# Script version
VERSION="1.0.0a"



#
# Usage / help message.
#

function usage_help
{
    local txt=(
    "Use this script to:"
    ""
    "1.     Help you reverse strings."
    "2.     Get the prime factors of numbers."
    "3.     Watch ASCII StarWars (ep IV)."
    ""
    "USAGE: $SCRIPT [options] <command> [arguments]"
    ""
    "OPTIONS:"
    " --help,    -h         Print help."
    " --version,     -v         Print version."
    ""
    "COMMAND: arguments in paranthesis ()"
    " reverse(string s)     Reverses and prints string s"
    " factors(args)         Prints the primefactors of submitted arguments."
    " starwars()            Shows you an ASCII version of starwars over telnet."
    )

    printf "%s\n" "${txt[@]}"
}

#
# Message to show when incorrect usage
#

function incorrect_usage
{
    local message="$1"
    local txt=(
    "For an overview of the command, execute:"
    "$SCRIPT --help"
    )

    [[ $message ]] && printf "$message\n"

    printf "%s\n" "${txt[@]}"
}

#
# Message to display version
#

function version
{
    local txt=(
    "$SCRIPT version $VERSION"
    )

    printf "%s\n" "${txt[@]}"
}

#
# Helper function to check if number is prime
#

function is_prime () {
    if [ "$1" == 1 ];
        then
        return 1
    fi;

    for (( i=2; i<$1; i++ ))
    do
        if (( $1%2 == 0));
            then
            return 1
        fi;
    done;
    return 0;
}

#
# Main assignment, reverses submitted string - if possible.
#

function app-reverse
{
    if [ "$1" != "" ];
    then
        echo "$1" | rev
    else
        echo "Empty argument, try again!"
    fi;
}

#
# Main assignment, prints arguments' prime factors.
# Uses is_prime as helper function.
#

function app-factors
{
    re='^[0-9]+$' #numerical numbers
    final_out=""
    if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
        incorrect_usage "Please suply arguments! This counts as bad usage!"
        exit 1
    else
        while [ "$1" != "" ];
        do
            out="$1: "
            if [[ $1 =~ $re ]]; then
                count=0
                for ((j=2; j<$1; j++))
                    do
                        is_prime "$j"
                        if [ $? != 1 ];
                            then
                                if (( $1%$j == 0));
                                    then
                                        out="$out $i"
                                        count=$count+1
                                fi;
                        fi;
                    done
                    if (($count == 0)); then
                        out="$out has no prime factorals."
                    fi;
            else
                out="$out non-numerical parameter."
            fi;
            final_out="${final_out}"$'\n'"${out}"
            shift
        done
        echo "$final_out"
    fi;
}

#
# Extra-assignment, for further credits.
#

function app-starwars
{
    telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl
}

#
# Main script-body, iterates through submitted parameters
#

while (( $# ))
do
    case "$1" in

        --help | -h)
            usage_help
            exit 0
        ;;

        --version | -v)
            version
            exit 0
        ;;

        reverse     \
        |   factors \
        |   starwars)
            command=$1
            shift
            app-$command $*
            exit 0
        ;;

        *)
            incorrect_usage "Options/command not recognized."
            exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done

incorrect_usage
exit 1
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Arithmetics in Bash

In arithmetic contexts within `((...))` you can omit the `$` in variable names (except the positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, ...),.
For example instead of this:

> ```
> if (( $1%$j == 0)); then
>     # ...
>
> if (($count == 0)); then
>     # ...
> ```

You can write slightly simpler as:

```
if (($1 % j == 0)); then
    # ...

if ((count == 0)); then
    # ...
```

There is also a strange statement that looked like a bug at first:

> ```
> count=$count+1
> ```

Given the initial value `count=0`, what will be the value of `count` after this statement?

> 0+1

That's not 1, but literally the string "0+1".
This doesn't make the script broken,
because the `(($count == 0))` condition that uses this will still work as intended, but only by chance.

As it is, this statement is confusing and misleading.
And you don't need a count, you need just a flag,
to indicate that at least one factors were found,
something like this:

```
found=
for ((j=2; j<$1; j++)); do
    is_prime "$j"
    if [ $? != 1 ]; then
        if (($1 % $j == 0)); then
            out="$out $i"
            found=1
        fi
    fi
done
if [ ! "$found" ]; then
    out="$out has no prime factors."
fi
```

#### Exit codes

This is strange:

> ```
> is_prime "$j"
> if [ $? != 1 ]; then
> ```

In a Bash shell, an exit code of 0 means success, non-0 means failure, as a general rule.
The `$? != 1` condition here seems to imply "success" (as in, "yes, the number is prime").
The straightforward way to convey that is to rewrite the condition using a value that actually means success:

```
is_prime "$j"
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
```

#### Use function exit codes directly

You can use the success/failure nature of exit codes directly in conditions.
Instead of this:

> ```
> is_prime "$j"
> if [ $? != 1 ]; then
> ```

You can write in one statement as:

```
if is_prime "$j"; then
```

#### Performance

In `is_prime`,
you loop from 2 until the target number.
It would be enough to go until half of that.

#### Printing long texts

Your approach to print longer messages is clever with `printf`,
but can be written simpler and easier using here-documents:

```
function usage_help
{
    cat << EOF
Use this script to:

1.     Help you reverse strings.
2.     Get the prime factors of numbers.
3.     Watch ASCII StarWars (ep IV).

USAGE:  [options] <command> [arguments]

...
EOF
}
```

#### Writing style

Although this is valid:

> ```
> function version
> {
> ```

The recommended modern writing style is this:

```
version() {
```

#### Redundant semicolons

Although not an error, the semicolons after the `fi`, `done` and `return 0` are redundant:

> ```
> for (( i=2; i<$1; i++ ))
> do
>     if (( $1%2 == 0));
>         then
>         return 1
>     fi;
> done;
> return 0;
> ```

#### Formatting

This may be a matter of taste, but I find this formatting strange:

> ```
> function is_prime () {
>     if [ "$1" == 1 ];
>         then
>         return 1
>     fi;
>
>     for (( i=2; i<$1; i++ ))
>     do
>         if (( $1%2 == 0));
>             then
>             return 1
>         fi;
>     done;
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Consider this alternative:

```
is_prime() {
    if [ "$1" = 1 ]; then
        return 1
    fi

    for ((i = 2; i < $1; i++)); do
        if (($1 % 2 == 0)); then
            return 1
        fi
    done
}
```

#### Simplification

Since non-empty values are *truthy* in Bash, instead of this:

> ```
> if [ "$1" != "" ];
> ```

You can write simpler like this:

```
if [ "$1" ];
```

#### Early returns

When you return or exit in an `if` statement,
you can eliminate the `else` statement,
and make the rest of the function flatter,
which is generally easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

I wish I had more time to answer and go a bit more in-depth (and come up with sample code) but right away, it looks **great**! Superbly easy to read, especially for me as a non-frequent BASH user. Two possible suggestions:

1. Can you abstract the repeated requirement that the parameter cannot be empty? It's the first `if` statement in `app-reverse` and `app-factors`. It could either be something called, or as part of `incorrect_usage`.
2. That big nested else-while-if-for concerns me. I wonder if you can have the first statement be a guard statement to exit the function if the conditions aren't met. Then you don't need to nest everything under `else`:

   ```
   if (!condition) {
       return 
   }
   // continue here...
   ```

Next, is there any way you could reduce or remove some of the loops? Referring to [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716), it may be considered best to avoid developing something hard to maintain. In my mind, a bash script is short and sweet. The loops make it more of an imperative *program* than quick script.

Comment: I'll definetely have a look at those things! I'll hold off on marking this as the answer until I have some more answers, just in case! :)